# Bd consulting wordpress to show the_excerpt();

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following query to extract the bd wordpress

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%".$keywords."%' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'";
```

I store information in an array

```
$arr[] = array('id' => $obj->ID, 'title' => $obj->post_title);
```

but as I can extract "the_excerpt();" or the_tags(); with a query like this?

I need to use Ajax Live Search to display results on screen

Comment: Dont use direct query like these...

Comment: Refer my answer given bellow and let me know if have any question ...

Answer (score 0):

For ajax in wordpress here is solution.

> http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

and for any data stored in posts, pages, and other custom post types here is solution.

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

If you find this information useful then give vote.

thanks.